# using unicode text in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, unicode, collation

I want to use unicode text in my site. I have nvarchar(max) data type in database to store the data. When I save unicode text into database, it works fine. However when i try to perform some sql operation the unicode text is changed to "?????"
Eg, the query below

```
declare @unicodetext nvarchar(250)
set @unicodetext='बन्द'
select @unicodetext
```

results

[image: sqlunicode]

What is the solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the default collation of the database?

Comment: @Oded The default collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
declare @unicodetext nvarchar(250)
set @unicodetext = N'बन्द'
select @unicodetext
```

Maybe you noticed that SQL Server uses `N` to any quoted string input when generating DDL scripts for you.

Comment: Good spot. Unicode text needs to be qualifies as such using the `N` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

you have to set your database collation to a collation that accepts this type of character or you can add the collation clause on your select like this (google told me this is a Hindi character)

```
declare @unicodetext nvarchar(250)
set @unicodetext='बन्द'
select @unicodetext
COLLATE Indic_General_90_CI_AS
```

that wont work, but I found this on BOL for SQL Server 2005:

> 4 The Hindi collation is deprecated in SQL Server 2005 because the
>   Windows 2000 sorting table is used in this SQL Server release. The
>   collation still exists in the server, but it will not be supported in
>   a future SQL Server release, and it does not show up in
>   ::fn_helpcollations().
>
> 5 The Hindi and Lithuanian_Classic collations are deprecated in SQL
>   Server 2005. These collations still exist in the server, but they will
>   not be supported in a future SQL Server release, and they do not show
>   up in ::fn_helpcollations().

for 2008:

> Hindi (India) - Not available at server level