# How to insert Arabic text via SQLCommand in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode, ado.net, sqlcommand

Am using SQLCommand to make an insert query like following:

```
db.Database.SQLCommand("sql statement" , "pars");
```

but when i type Arabic (Unicode) text into the SQL statement it's only shows question marks in the database.

and when i do it as a database query in SQL Server management studio it works fine! please help

Comment: Is your database column type nvarchar? Did you try [prefixing your value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10530373/205233) with `N` to signify it as unicode? Example: `N'باالالا'`

Comment: prefix `n` in sql datatypes tells to SQL Server I would like to store unicode text ,so you should modify `text` to `ntext` , `varchar` to `nvarchar` and so on

Comment: Please refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912486/update-a-varchar-column-with-arabic-names-in-sql/33913090#33913090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the collation for you database to be arabic, and also that of the table column.

Also make sure the column is NVARCHAR and not VARCHAR

[image]

[image]